# Compare excel columns using specific statements

Tags: excel, compare

I have an excel file that contains multiple columns and many rows.
Two of those columns are phone number and date.

What I would like to accomplish is to check if two rows share the SAME date and the SAME phone number. This could be a function in another column that outputs the index of the rows that share the same data or 0 if there is no found index.

I know how to do this in SQL, or any programming language, but for some reason excel has me stuck on this for quite a bit of time. This is the function I tried to use, but I fear the results are inaccurate: IF(AND(MATCH(E2,E3:E4761,0)MATCH(I2,I3:I4761,0)),1,2)

Column E represents the phone number and I represents the date.

I tried to output 1 if there was a match and 2 if not to begin with, but it's too general because I need it to check the same row each time and get all the available results.

Thank you for your time, I would appreciate any help on the matter.

Comment: Are you looking for any pairs of rows that match, or starting with a specific row and seeing if other rows match that?

Comment: I need the function to output all the indexes of the rows that match the one being tested. So for example if row A matches row B and C, I need the output for A to be B, C. For B to be A and C. Expect not letters, indices.

Comment: Please add sample data with expected output to clarify your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind including the row that the formula is in in your list, and if you have Microsoft Excel 365 with the `FILTER` function, you can use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER([Column1],[Column2]=[@Column2],[Column3]=[@Column3]))
```

*Note that I used a **Table** and structured references*

[image]

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for, however I would like to test two columns and output the result on third, not three columns like in your example. However I think I can figure it out from here, thank you sir.

Comment: @ZedZerg Glad to help. And you can modify it in various ways.  By the way, the function **IS** only testing two columns: Column2 and Column3.  If you have problems adapting to your specific requirements, please **edit** your question to provide representative samples of your input and desired output; and add a comment to my response that you did so in order that I may be aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula looks perfectly fine to me except for a missing comma. It should be this:

```
IF(AND(MATCH(E2,E3:E4761,0),MATCH(I2,I3:I4761,0)),1,2)
```

Or, you can use `CountIf` function to replace `Match`

```
IF(AND(COUNTIF(E3:E4761,E2),COUNTIF(I3:I4761,I2)),1,2)
```

Comment: In theory it works, I know, but I need to know the indices of the matching rows. This will just tell me if there are matching rows, but I need the rows' indices.

Comment: Okay, so you need the cell address of each match?